# Facebook iFrame Application navigation links

Tags: facebook

I am working in a facebook iframe application, the problem I am having are the links in my navigation. what URL shall I use ? if I use the `app.facebook.com/my-app/page` then it first redirects where it shows facebook's logo and then goes to the page. and If I use normal links of my server then the Application opens up outside facebook's environment if loaded in a new tab, like the link is opened in a new tab by a right click. How to solve this?

Also note that i am using just the JS SDK, all the pages are simple HTML.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to refresh Facebook you need to use http://app.facebook.com/my-app/page and target top

```
<a href="http://app.facebook.com/my-app/page" target="_top"></a>
```

And if you only need to refresh contens (just inside of iframe) use page

```
<a href="page"></a>
```